# How to properly subclass ComboBoxItem in C++ with WinUI 3?

Tags: c++, winui-3, winui

I am trying to discern the most efficient way to provide items to a ComboBox that have associated data.  Bing chat provided something that looks very promising, but I can't seem to get it to compile.

This is using WinUI 3, v1.3.  I'm looking for a C++ solution.

Create subclass:

```
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls;

struct CustomComboBoxItem : public ComboBoxItem {
};
```

Add to ComboBox:

```
comboBox.Items().Append(CustomComboBoxItem());
```

Access in handler:

```
comboBox.SelectionChanged([](const IInspectable& sender, const SelectionChangedEventArgs& e) {
    auto    comboBox_ = sender.as<ComboBox>();
    auto    selectedItem = selectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems().GetAt(0).as<CustomComboBoxItem>();
    if (selectedItem != nullptr) {
        // Have fun
    }
});
```

The problem is that, while this looks great, it ends up with lots of compilation errors:

```
1>D:\Software\Generated Files\winrt\base.h(2016,13): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'nullptr' to 'CustomComboBoxItem'
1>D:\Software\Generated Files\winrt\base.h(2016,13): message : 'CustomComboBoxItem::CustomComboBoxItem': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types
1>D:\Software\Source\File.cpp(91,1): message : could be 'CustomComboBoxItem::CustomComboBoxItem(CustomComboBoxItem &&)'
1>D:\Software\Generated Files\winrt\base.h(2016,13): message : 'CustomComboBoxItem::CustomComboBoxItem(CustomComboBoxItem &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'nullptr' to 'CustomComboBoxItem &&'
1>D:\Software\Generated Files\winrt\base.h(2016,20): message : Reason: cannot convert from 'nullptr' to 'CustomComboBoxItem'
1>D:\Software\Source\File.cpp(91,1): message : or       'CustomComboBoxItem::CustomComboBoxItem(const CustomComboBoxItem &)'
1>D:\Software\Generated Files\winrt\base.h(2016,13): message : 'CustomComboBoxItem::CustomComboBoxItem(const CustomComboBoxItem &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'nullptr' to 'const CustomComboBoxItem &'
1>D:\Software\Generated Files\winrt\base.h(2016,20): message : Reason: cannot convert from 'nullptr' to 'const CustomComboBoxItem'
1>D:\Software\Generated Files\winrt\base.h(2016,13): message : while trying to match the argument list '(nullptr)'
1>D:\Software\Generated Files\winrt\base.h(2109,26): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'CustomComboBoxItem winrt::impl::as<To,winrt::impl::unknown_abi,0>(From *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            To=CustomComboBoxItem,
1>            From=winrt::impl::unknown_abi
1>        ]
1>D:\Software\Source\File.cpp(158,70): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'CustomComboBoxItem winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown::as<CustomComboBoxItem>(void) const' being compiled
```

Hopefully it's something very simple I am doing wrong.  Can anyone help fix what is needed to get this working?  Or is subclassing ComboBoxItem simply not possible?

Comment: Of course you *can* subclass `ComboBoxItem`. Whether doing so it a good idea is a different question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl So how would one go about successfully subclassing `ComboBoxItem`?  Or alternatively, what would you recommend as the best approach to compose a ComboBox where you need to associate non-trivial data with each item?

Comment: Could you please tell us what you want to achieve via subclassing ComboBoxItem? "provide items to a ComboBox that have associated data. " I suggest you could populate the ComboBox by adding objects directly to the Items collection or by binding the ItemsSource property to a data source.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT We are looking to associate "non-trivial" additional data with each item, that we can access in the selection changed event.  After further learning, it seems that the best approach is to make a struct as a subclass of `IInspectable` and set that as the `Tag()` of the `ComboBoxItem`.  Unless there would be a better approach?